# Как реализовать отправку данных по типу login и password на сервер?

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, post

Есть сайт, где есть пока только:

MySite:

- Web1:
- auth.js
- auth.css
- index.html

Как реализовать отправку данных авторизации на сервер? я пока использую IIS в Windows. Также подскажите, почему реализация кода ниже работает:

MySite/Web1/index.html:

- windows.open(“../Web2/index.html”)

А ведь работает и без гиппер ссылки, а по простому относительному пути, хотя откуда серверу знать, что я вообще нажал на кнопку в браузере на другом устройстве. А просто сохранить введенные данные логин и пароля в файл на сервере он реализовать не может, видите ли нет возможности работать с файловой системой. Зато может предложить юзеру, сохранить у него. Я не понимаю как это работает, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Понимаю, вопрос заучит тривиально, в интернете много чего по этому поводу, а вы попробуйте сформулировать